# Simulating UDAF on Pyspark for encapsulation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning Spark with PySpark, and just hit a wall when trying to make things cleaner.

Say a have a dataframe that looks like this. (of course, with way more columns and rows)

```
A | B |   C
--+---+------
a | 1 | 1.300
a | 2 | 2.500
a | 3 | 1.000
b | 1 | 120.0
b | 4 | 34.20
c | 2 | 3.442
```

and I want to run a bunch of `groupby -> agg` on it, using basic `pyspark.sql.functions` , like `count()` and `mean()`, like this:

```
df.groupby("A")\
    .agg(mean("B").alias("B_mean"),
         sum("C").alias("C_sum"),
         (countDistinct("B")/avg("C")).alias("New_metric"))
```

It works fine, runs relatively fast, and gives me the desired results.

But, eventually, slightly more complex functions will be needed, and, also, we want to make these easier to test.

How can one encapsulate these functions? Using `lambda`? Some way around UDFs?

I'm aware of UDAFs and that it's possible to write them in SCALA and import the code to PySpark, but, since all of our code base is already in Python, I would like to explore other options.

P.S.: We are running Spark 1.6.0

Comment: you can just wrap your code inside  `return()` of your function as in `def myFun(df): return(...)` , and then run `myFun(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function can be defined as a combination of `pyspark.sql.functions`:

- YES - go this way. For example:

  ```
  def sum_of_squares(col):
      return sum(col * col)

  df.select(sum_of_squares(df["foo"]])

  df.groupBy("foo").agg(sum_of_squares(df["bar"]])
  ```
- NO - use RDD.